# How to specify index.mapping.ignore_malformed in elasticsearch python lowlevel client?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
es.indices.create(index='report', ignore=400)
es_reponse = es.index(index='reports',doc_type='text',body=report_json)
```

I am getting

> RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'mapper
>   [table.rows.endDate] of different type, current_type [date],
>   merged_type [text]')

this error and can be solved by setting index.mapping.ignore_malformed : false, But I don't know where to specify this in code?
i am using `elasticsearch 7.0.5`

Answer (score 2):

You can create index with this parameter in `Python` with:

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Index
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es=Elasticsearch(['ES_URL:ES_PORT'])


index = Index('my_index', es)
index.settings(
     number_of_shards=6,
     number_of_replicas=2,
     index={'mapping':{'ignore_malformed':False}}) //or True
index.create()
```

And this is how it looks like on `Elasticsearch`:

```
[root@host]$ curl -XGET ES_URL:ES_PORT/my_index/_settings?pretty
{
  "my_index" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "mapping" : {
          "ignore_malformed" : "false"
        },
        "number_of_shards" : "6",
        "provided_name" : "my_index",
        "creation_date" : "1573646292390",
        "number_of_replicas" : "2",
        "uuid" : "e__BuX-KSSeoR2LXQXaWkA",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "6020499"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to index json object coming from rest api directly in  elasticsearch. I can't use elasticsearch_dsl because i am not storing data in models. How should i add documents in index directly coming from api (json) ?

Comment: can we index **json object** directly in elasticsearch?  @dejanmarich

Comment: you can index json object, because Elasticsearch stores documents as json objects

Comment: @AbdulSamad - ignore malformed is defined in index mapping, that has nothing to do with inserting data operations, you just create index with this setting, and then you do your standard insert operations..

Comment: Thanks mate for the help. I have just started working on elasticsearch with python,  i'll be glad if you share any examples/links related to my stuff. Thanks

Comment: you need to ask another question, this one has nothing to do with this