# How to index large json response in elasticsearch in python ? using Elasticsearch DSL

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I found this approach in the documentation : 
https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

```
class Article(Document):
    title = Text(analyzer='snowball', fields={'raw': Keyword()})
    body = Text(analyzer='snowball')
    tags = Keyword()
    published_from = Date()
    lines = Integer()
```

and indexing like

```
# create and save and article
article = Article(meta={'id': 42}, title='Hello world!', tags=['test'])
article.body = ''' looong text '''
article.published_from = datetime.now()
article.save()
```

But this approach is not working out for me because I have very large JSON containing fields more than 100, and I have multiple JSON just like that. It would be difficult  to convert JSON in this form :

```
article = Article(meta={'id': 42}, title='Hello world!', tags=['test'])
```

## **Any Idea, how to index json directly without model like wrapper?**

Comment: Have you tried to convert to json the Article instance with .__dict__ magic method?

Comment: i don't want to use this approach. In this example Article(meta={'id': 42}, title='Hello world!', tags=['test']) contains only 3 args, and in my case there are more than 100 fields. and i have json already so no need of magic __dict__ method. I just want to index it directly without above mentioned approach.

Comment: OK, so you need to send the dict with the document  inside  a json {
    '_op_type': 'index',
    '_index': 'index-name',
    '_type': 'article',
    '_source': <output_of_dict_trnasformed_object>,
}

Comment: then you use the bulk method, have a look here: https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.bulk

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the dict-structure of json without converting everything to your DSL. Just use the normal elasticsearch client, e.g. see the example for the low level client here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py

Please do note that if you have a large number of docs, it is very useful to use the bulk-import API, which can be magnitudes faster.

Comment: I used this too, But i have also date fields in my json and elasticsearch detects date and is giving  **RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'mapper  [table.rows.endDate] of different type, current_type [date], merged_type [text]')** , and solution to this was to set index.mapping.ignore_malformed: false. But i don't know where to set this setting in code?

Comment: Here is the link of the question i asked : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58835485/how-to-specify-index-mapping-ignore-malformed-in-elasticsearch-python-lowlevel-c]

Comment: The first answer provides the answer how to set ignore_malformed

Comment: But it is using elasticsearch-dsl for this :/

Comment: You should be able to set this when saving the document,please search the docs for that

Comment: I have spent 2 days, didn't found anything, but thanks for the answer